# this.context.PropTypes is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-proptypes

I am taking the wes bos's course on react. Following through the lectures I came across this problem i can't seem to figure out.

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers';

class StorePicker extends React.Component {

    goToStore(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("provoked");
    const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
    console.log(`going to /store/${storeId}`)
        this.context.PropTypes.transitionTo(`/store/${storeId}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}>
                <h2> Please Enter A Store </h2>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Store Name" 
                defaultValue={getFunName()} ref={ (input) => {this.storeInput = input}} /> 
                <button type="submit"> Visit Store </button>            
            </form>
        )

    }   
}

StorePicker.contextTypes = {
router: React.PropTypes.object 
}

export default StorePicker;
```

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Answer (score 0):

import prop types first

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

and then use history to redirect

```
this.props.history.push(`store/${storeId}`);
```

and your router

```
router: PropTypes.object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
React.PropTypes has been deprecated. So you have to install [prop-types][1]
```

library . And modify your code like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class StorePicker extends React.Component {

    goToStore(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("provoked");
    const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
    console.log(`going to /store/${storeId}`)
        this.props.history.push(`store/${storeId}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}>
                <h2> Please Enter A Store </h2>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Store Name" 
                defaultValue={getFunName()} ref={ (input) => {this.storeInput = input}} /> 
                <button type="submit"> Visit Store </button>            
            </form>
        )

    }   
}

StorePicker.contextTypes = {
router: PropTypes.object 
}

export default StorePicker;
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: 'PropTypes' is defined but never used.

Comment: Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/StorePicker.js
Module not found: 'prop-types' in D:\TTC\Tech\Wes Bos - React For Beginners\Starter-Files\catch-of-the-day\src\components